# Test Results from Gitlab CI/CD pipeline to Azure Devops

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, gitlab-ci

We can try to communicate from gitlab test automation application to Azure Devops Test Plan APIs. But i don't know how to communicate gitlab to azure? What are the requirements? How many integration methods are there?

Working Principle of system is we have a repo, have a java gradle cucumber selenium project. We want the repo to run all tests after each merge in gitlab, then transfer each test result to azure devops via gitlab and display the results such as pass fail scenarios from azure devops.

How can we solve this problem?
Thanks :)